# Checking for the next highest/lowest values in a Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to create an order system that assigns slots to customers based on available capacity.

Each day I can choose the numberOfSlots and the capacityPerSlot.
For my test I chose 3 slots and 3 capacity per slot for a total of 9 slots.

Each customer can state a preferred slot number, 0 in this case.

```
int numberOfSlots = 2; capacityPerSlot = 2;
int preferredSlot = 0
```

For each order I get I have to check if there is still capacity left in the customers preferred slot. If there is I assign that slot to him. If there isn't I give him the next slot with the lowest index (+/-) and available capacity. If there are no slots left I assign nothing.

Here is my code thusfar:

```
int givenSlot = 0, count = 0;
HashMap<Integer, Integer> slots = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
Iterator iterator = slots.entrySet().iterator();
Iterator iterator2 = slots.entrySet().iterator();

if (slots.size() < (numberOfSlots + 1) * (capacityPerSlot + 1)) {
                if (!slots.containsValue(preferredSlot)) {
                    givenSlot = preferredSlot;
                    slots.put(count, preferredSlot);
                    count++;
                } else {
                    int valueCount = 0;
                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        Map.Entry slot = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
                        if (slot.getValue().equals(preferredSlot)) {
                            valueCount++;
                        }
                    }
                    if (valueCount <= capacityPerSlot) {
                        givenSlot = preferredSlot;
                        slots.put(count, preferredSlot);
                        count++;
                    } else {
                        int valueCount2 = 0;
                        int i = 1;
                        while (iterator2.hasNext()) {
                            Map.Entry slot2 = (Map.Entry) iterator2.next();
                            if (slot2.getValue().equals(preferredSlot + i)) {
                                valueCount2++;
                                if (valueCount2 > capacityPerSlot) {
                                    i++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (valueCount2 <= capacityPerSlot) {
                            givenSlot = preferredSlot + i;
                            slots.put(count, preferredSlot + i);
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

My code already works, if there hasn't been an order with the preferred slot number before and if the capacity for the preferred slot number is reached, but there is still capacity left for the preferred slot + 1.

But if the capacity for slot 0 and slot 1 are completely used up, I don't know how to get my code to check if there is availabilty in slot 2:

```
slots.put(100, 0);
slots.put(101, 0);
slots.put(102, 0);
slots.put(103, 1);
slots.put(104, 1);
slots.put(105, 1);
```

If I add those "orders", I don't assign a slot, when it should be assigning slot 2. How can I get my code to check for an undefined number of next slots, that are still inside of the range that I chose beforehand?

Comment: What do the key and values in the map represent? Are the keys order numbers and the values slot numbers? Or are the keys customer numbers and you can only have 1 order per customer? Some explanation of the model might help.

Comment: I think I can see what you are trying to do but the data structure you have chosen is really not appropriate for the problem. Maps are designed for easy access to values when given keys. Whereas you are having to count entries according to the values. That's just not what Maps are designed for. You can solve the problem using them but you would be much better off starting with a better data structure. For example a map from a slot number to a list of order numbers would make your code much simpler.

Comment: The values are my slot numbers and the keys don't really have a meaning. I was just told to use a HashMap for this task. Each customer can only have 1 order, but I already rule that out with an exception beforehand. I don't need help with the order system only with the slot part, that's why I excluded the other information.

Comment: Then why not use a `HashMap` where the keys are the slot numbers and the values are the number of orders in that slot? That'd be much much simpler code for you to write.

Comment: It's an assignment with clear instructions of what classes and methods to use. I already handled the orders beforehand. I was just struggeling with the slot part for days and my instructor told me to try it with a HashMap

Comment: Well then I expect you'll find my answer helpful as it explains how to solve the problem of slot availability using a `HashMap`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a different data structure.

For example:

```
Map<Integer,Integer> slotCounts;
```

could represent a map from a slot number to a list of order numbers.

Checking if a slot is available would be `slotCounts.getOrDefault(slot, 0) < capacityPerSlot`.

Finding the next slot available would be:

```
for (int slot = preferredSlot; slot < numberOfSlots; slot++) {
    int count = slotCounts.getOrDefault(slot, 0);
    if (count < capacityPerSlot) {
        slotsCount.put(slot, count + 1);
        break;
    }
}
```